# Research Training Support Grant

Tags: phd, funding

I've managed to secure a National Environmental Research Council (NERC) funded PhD project (I'm a UK resident and student), and understand that the funding comprises of:

- Tuition fees
- Stipend
- Research training support grant (composed of research and training budgets)

So the tuition fees and stipend are paid year on year, but there's a single figure associated with the research and training budgets for the duration of the project.
I'm confused as to what the research and training budgets would or could be used for? Also as to whether it is something that is paid to myself, or something to be claimed against? I've tried searching for information specific to NERC or other DTPs, but can't seem to find out any information.

I hope this doesn't come across as dense! Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: There's some generic information [here](http://www.nerc.ac.uk/funding/available/postgrad/responsive/dtp/dtp-terms/) on page 2 and a little bit more on page 11 of [this document](http://www.nerc.ac.uk/funding/application/howtoapply/forms/studenthandbook/).